# Intersection in mysql

Tags: mysql

my first query

```
SELECT ID FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' 
AND ID IN (Select object_id FROM wp_term_relationships, wp_terms
           WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id =18) 
ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

produce result

```
 31 and 28
```

and my second query

```
SELECT ID FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' 
AND ID IN (Select object_id FROM wp_term_relationships, wp_terms 
           WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id =8) 
ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

will produce

```
31 and 33
```

I need to get intersection of both query result.ie, `31` only. how can we get it using mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An intersect is nothing more than an inner join, actually:

```
select
    a.ID as ID
from
    (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' AND ID IN (Select object_id FROM wp_term_relationships, wp_terms WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id =8 or wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id =18)) as a,
    (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' AND ID IN (Select object_id FROM wp_term_relationships, wp_terms WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id =18 or wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id =18)) as b
where
    a.ID=b.ID
```

From the top of my head. I just copy & pasted your queries, btw.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be like this:

```
SELECT FROM (that entire first query) WHERE ID IN (that entire second query)
```

I make no promises about its efficiency...

Answer (score 0):

Your query is somehow not clear.
Look at the second query. 
You have the following

```
wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id =18   OR
wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id =18
```

Answer (score 0):

hmmm intersection - try inner join :P